# I'm trying to implement delete method of BST but i cant figure out the problem

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

After calling the delete() against an integer value in my Binary Search Tree, the number still not removed from the bst and no error is given and can't figure out the problem thanks in advance

```
delete(data) {

  function removeNode(node, data) {
    if (node === null) {
      return node;
    }
    if (data === node.data) {
      if (node.right === null && node.left === null) {
        node = null;
        return node;
      } else if (node.right === null) {
        node = node.left;
        return node
      } else if (node.left === null) {
        node = node.right;
        return node
      } else {
        // node with two leaves
        var tempNode = node.right;
        while (tempNode.left !== null) {
          tempNode = tempNode.left;
        }
        node.data = tempNode.data;
        tempNode = null;
      }

    } else if (data < node.data) {
      node.left = removeNode(node, data);
      return node;
    } else if (data > node.data) {
      removeNode(node.right, data);
      return node;
    }

  }
  this.root = removeNode(this.root, data);
}
}
const mybst = new BST();
mybst.add(20);
mybst.add(25);
console.log(mybst.findMax());
console.log(mybst.findMin());
mybst.delete(25);
console.log(mybst.findMax());
```

//I expected 25 to be removed in this case but i still have 25 when log mybst.findMax(). Thanx in advance.

Comment: Likely cause is the keyword `this` (in `this.root`) not representing what you expect it to.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What else would it refer to when calling `mybst.delete(25)`?

Comment: I have no way of knowing that because you've only provided a snippet of the code you are using.

Comment: The syntax he used for defining the function only makes sense if it's a method of the `BST` class, he didn't show the rest of it.

Comment: I think the problem is the `node with two leaves` case. It doesn't change any `left` or `right` nodes, and doesn't return anything.

Comment: ah - good catch. It would certainly seem plausible that is tree would have two leaves off the root.

Comment: the issue is within the "node with two leaves" but i don't where the error is in there!